# can pandas handle datetime.datetime subclasses correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The code snippet below appears to show:

1. `datetime.datetime` objects have no `nanosecond` attribute on construction
2. when passed into `pandas`' `index.get_loc()` they seem to aquire a `nanosecond` attribute, possibly through conversion into `Timestamp`
3. if the object passed into `get_loc()` is a subclass of `datetime` however, it does not acquire a `nanosecond` attribute and the code fails with `datetime_sub object has no attribute 'nanosecond'`

The error is raised from the conversion from `datetime` to `Timestamp` in `pandas`' `datetimes.py`.
I'm not sure how to look further as the code enters what I imagine to be a C binary at that point.
It could be that pandas performs this conversion to `Timestamp` by checking for `datetime` as a type in a manner that excludes `datetime` subtypes.

Questions:

1. Am I doing this wrong?
2. Is this a bug in pandas?
3. Assuming I must use a subclass of `datetime`, Is there a way to get around this?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime from datetime

class datetime_sub(datetime):
    pass

dt = datetime(2012, 10, 22)
dt_s = datetime_sub(2012, 10, 22)

try:
    print(dt.nanosecond)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)

ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range('2012-10-1', '2012-10-30'))
dt_loc = ind.get_loc(dt)
dt_s_loc = ind.get_loc(dt_s)
```

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve here? I don't see your code raising any errors that aren't expected. Other than that, do you *have* to use Python's native datetime class? `pandas` "natively" uses `numpy`'s [datetime64](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html) data type to store timestamps at nanosecond resolution. So I'd recommend using that in the first place, but that's for convenience and efficiency (not strictly needed to get *correct* results).

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks. I should have clarified that I am having to use pandas 0.24.0. Pandas versions beyond that change some behavior that breaks our code in several places requiring work we haven't yet allocated time to. From what you say about it working on pandas 1.2.3 it sounds like it's a pandas bug which has been fixed somewhere between 0.24.0 and 1.2.3. I'll give it a try and report back....

Comment: ok that of course makes it more difficult. I don't know all of your constraints but maybe a conversion from Python standard lib datetime to pd.Timestamp / np.datetime64 is worth a thought. Perhaps in relevant places only, prior to calling pandas methods that fail otherwise.